# True of False :A liner combination of (root irrational number) $a^b$ $(a \in Q_+ b \in Q) $ is a irrational number?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\text{Let} $  $a^b$ $(a \in Q_+$ and $ b \in Q$ \ {${0}$}$) $  $=$ $P_{(a,b)}$  and If $c=\dfrac{P_{(a_1,b_1)}}{P_{(a_2,b_2)}}$ is a rational number then we say :$P_{(a_1,b_1)}$  and $P_{(a_2,b_2)}$ is the same kind

I think about this two propositions

1) If $P_{(a_i,b_i)}$ and $P_{(a_j,b_j)}$ isn't the same kind

then $k_1P_{(a_1,b_1)}+k_2P_{(a_2,b_2)}+...+k_nP_{(a_n,b_n)}=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $k_1=k_2=...=k_n=0$

2) If $P_{(a_i,b_i)}$ and $P_{(a_j,b_j)}$ isn't the same kind

and not all $a_i=0$

then $\sum_1^n a_iP_{(a_j,b_j)}$ is a irrational number

If the proposition has proof before? Thanks for any help.

Comment: $P_{(2,3)}/P_{(2,4)}=1/2$ is rational, but $P_{(2,3)}\ne P_{(2,4)}$. Also, if you mean for the $k_i$ and the $a_i$ to be rational, please edit that into your question.

Comment: What does "same kind" mean?

Comment: I dont mean the normal equal...I mean a equivalence class..To prevent the occurrence of certain circumstances like $\sqrt2+(-\sqrt2)=0$

Comment: I dont know how to express it exactly ,if anyone can know what I mean ,help edit it ,thanks.